# django's self.client.force_login doesn't work

Tags: python, django, testcase

I am using django 3.2 and self.client.force_login in test package doesn't log in.
this is the setUp method:

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        email='asdf@gmail.com',
        password='hiwa_asdf',
        name='smile as we go ahead'
    )
    self.client.force_login(self.user)
```

and here the test method:

```
def test_update_uer_profile(self):
    """testing if update user profile works"""

    data = {
        'name': 'Angry as hell',
        'password': 'hi there john'
    }
    response = self.client.patch(me_url, data)
    print(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.user.refresh_from_db()
    self.assertEqual(self.user.name, data['name'])
    self.assertTrue(self.user.check_password(data['password']))
```

and here's the result:

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
b'{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}'
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_update_uer_profile (user.tests.test_user_api.PrivateApiTest)
testing if update user profile works
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming_projects\Django\drf\recipe_app_api\user\tests\test_user_api.py", line 133, in test_update_uer_profile
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
AssertionError: 401 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.257s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**`force_authenticate(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication) if you are using DRF

```
def setUp(self) -> None:
    self.user = User.objects.create_user(
        email='asdf@gmail.com',
        password='hiwa_asdf',
        name='smile as we go ahead'
    )
    self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)
```

Comment: If user is logged-out in one test using `self.client.logout() ` or `self.client.force_authenticate(user=None)` then how can we login the user in the next test. Currently logging-out once won't re-login using `self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)`